# Processes spawned by taskset not respecting environment variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I've run into an issue where an intel compiler generated program that I'm running with taskset has been putting its temporary files into the working directory instead of /tmp (defined by environment variable TMPDIR). If run by itself, it works correctly. If run with taskset (e.g.

```
taskset -c 0 <program>
```

Then it seems to completely ignore the TMPDIR environment variable. I then verified this by writing a quick bash script as follows:

contents of test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $TMPDIR
```

When run by itself:

```
$ export TMPDIR=/tmp
$ test.sh
/tmp
```

When run through taskset:

```
$ export TMPDIR=/tmp
$ taskset -c 1 test.sh
""
```

Another test.  If I export the TMPDIR variable inside of my script and then use taskset to spawn a new process, it doesn't know about that variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
export TMPDIR=/tmp
taskset -c 1 sh -c export
```

When run, the list of exported variables does not include TMPDIR. It works correctly with any other exported environment variable. If i diff the output of:

```
export
```

and

```
taskset -c 1 bash -c export
```

Then I see that there are 4 changes. The taskset spawned export doesn't have LD_LIBRARY_PATH, NLSPATH (intel compiler variable), SHLVL is 3 instead of 1, and TMPDIR is missing.
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Sorry, I guess it doesn't go without saying that TMPDIR is set in my environment but it is.  It's been exported with

    export TMPDIR=/tmp

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually see evidence here that `$TMPDIR` is set in your environment.  I can replicate the behavior you describe if I set `TMPDIR` as a local shell variable, like this:

```
$ TMPDIR=/tmp
$ taskset -c 0 sh -c 'echo TMPDIR: $TMPDIR'
```

Which yields:

```
TMPDIR:
```

But if I export `TMPDIR` to the environment, it works as one would expect:

```
$ TMPDIR=/tmp
$ export TMPDIR
$ taskset -c 0 sh -c 'echo TMPDIR: $TMPDIR'
TMPDIR: /tmp
```

Are you certain that `TMPDIR` is set in your environment?  You can use the `env` command to dump your current environment:

```
$ env | grep TMPDIR
TMPDIR=/tmp
```

If I take your updated script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export TMPDIR=/tmp
taskset -c 1 sh -c export
```

And run this on my CentOS system:

```
$ sh taskset.sh  | grep TMPDIR
export TMPDIR="/tmp"
```

It works as advertised.  I'm not sure what's going on in your environment.

Comment: I tried your commands on my system (CENTOS 6.3) and I get TMPDIR: as the response.

Comment: I'm running these commands on a CentOS 6.4 system.

Comment: Well then I'm more confused than ever .... It does seem to work correctly with any other variable name, just not TMPDIR.